# I want one user to login from only one browser at a time

Tags: session, servlets, https, servlet-listeners

I have done small web application project using JDBC + Servlets + JSP, in which i am letting user to login and i am providing him a session after successful login. By traditional mechanism one user can login from multiple browsers at a time (one user with multiple sessions), But i want that user to be logged out from previous browser when he tries to login from new browser (only one session for user) functionality. please provide me logic to implement

I haven't tried anything